# Get the value of a JSON Array C# using Json.Linq

Tags: c#, json

I like to get the first value of JSON array.

My JSON:

```
{
    "userlist": [
        {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "Max",
        }
    ],
}
```

What I have:

```
public int JSONId(string JSONstring)
        {
            JObject responseJSON = JObject.Parse(ResponseGETSearchForCorrectID);
            int id = (int)JArray.Parse(ResponseGETSearchForCorrectID).Children()["userlist"]["id"].First();

            return id;
        }
```

But I get this error:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

I tried also:

```
int idPackage = responseJSON["userlist"]["id"].Values;
```

But doesn`t work too because I get an exception with the info, that this is an array.

What I do wrong here? Have someone a soulution?

Thank you.

Comment: trailing comma will break it

Comment: your JSON is invalid. remove , after the ]

Comment: I edited and made the JSON file shorter to understand more easily. There is more stuff after ] but thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way

```
int idPackage = responseJSON["userlist"][0]["id"].Value<int>();
```

Since userliat is an array, you have to access the objects via index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
int id = obj.userlist[0].id;
```